# Presave function

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list

I have a choice filed (Radio Button) call **Test1** with 2 options, **BHCD** and **Prison**, I also have another choice filed (Radio Button) call **Test2**, with **BHDC1**, **BHDC2**, **BHDC3** and **Prison1** , **Prison2**, **Prison3**.
What I want is if the users select BHDC then users must select one of the 3 options in BHDC and same for Prison. my below code doesn't seems to work.

if ($("input[id^='Test1'][type='radio']:checked").val() == "BHDC" && $(
'select[id^="Test2"]').val('')) {
alert("Please select one of the options: BHDC1 , BHDC2 , BHDC3");
return false;
}

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for seems to be a cascading dropdown list. You can refer to the below blogs for more help.

For SharePoint On-Prem or SharePoint Online classic experience:https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/cascading-of-lookup-dropdown-fields-on-sharepoint-2013-and-o/

[Multilevel Cascading Dropdowns for SharePoint 2013, 2016, and O365 Classic forms](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t52Z8Snt760)

For SharePoint Online modern experience, it may be better to use [PowerApps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kzvMbmb5pmo).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SharePoint online list classic New/ Edit Form use below JavaScript code

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    
     if ($("input[name^='Test1']:checked").val() == "Prison") {
              $("input[value='Prison1']").prop("checked", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC1']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC2']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC3']").attr("disabled", true);
              
                $("input[value='Prison1']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='Prison2']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='Prison3']").attr("disabled", false);
              
            } else if ($("input[name^='Test1']:checked").val() == "BHCD"){
              $("input[value='BHDC1']").prop("checked", true);
              $("input[value='Prison1']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='Prison2']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='Prison3']").attr("disabled", true);
              
                $("input[value='BHDC1']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='BHDC2']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='BHDC3']").attr("disabled", false);
            }
    
        $("input[name^='Test1']").change(function() {
           if ($("input[name^='Test1']:checked").val() == "Prison") {
              $("input[value='Prison1']").prop("checked", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC1']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC2']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='BHDC3']").attr("disabled", true);
              
                $("input[value='Prison1']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='Prison2']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='Prison3']").attr("disabled", false);
              
            } else if ($("input[name^='Test1']:checked").val() == "BHCD"){
              $("input[value='BHDC1']").prop("checked", true);
              $("input[value='Prison1']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='Prison2']").attr("disabled", true);
              $("input[value='Prison3']").attr("disabled", true);
              
                $("input[value='BHDC1']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='BHDC2']").attr("disabled", false);
              $("input[value='BHDC3']").attr("disabled", false);
            }

    });
});
</script>
```